# OpenAI API: openai.api_key = os.getenv() not working

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

I am just trying some simple functions in Python with OpenAI APIs but running into an error:

I have a valid API secret key which I am using.

Code:

```
>>> import os
>>> import openai
>>> openai.api_key = os.getenv("I have placed the key here")
>>> response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003", prompt="Say this is a test", temperature=0, max_tokens=7)
```

[image: Simple test]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And you've cut out the most important part of the traceback.

Comment: It looks like you pasted your actual API key, but `os.getenv()` expects the NAME of the ENV variable, not the value itself.  If you're going to just paste the value of the key, I think you can just do: `openai.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"` and paste your key there.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: Apologies. I will make sure to follow the standards. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Option 1: OpenAI API key *not* as an environment variable

Change this...

`openai.api_key = os.getenv('sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')`

...to this.

`openai.api_key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

#### Option 2: OpenAI API key as an environment variable (recommended)

Change this...

`openai.api_key = os.getenv('sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`)

...to this...

`openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')`

#### [How do I set the OpenAI API key as an environment variable?](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety)

STEP 1: Open *System* properties and select *Advanced system settings*

[image: Screenshot 1]

STEP 2: Select *Environment Variables*

[image: Screenshot 2]

STEP 3: Select *New*

STEP 4: Add your name/key value pair

```
Variable name: OPENAI_API_KEY

Variable value: sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

STEP 5: Restart your computer **(IMPORTANT!)**

Comment: Works like a charm. Yes, missed the stupid getenv thing. I am new to Python. More of a PS guy. Thanks a lot

Comment: see https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/494